# Is there a way to use an SQL Join in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, join

I have a query that I used before in MS SQL and would like to use in Oracle.
However it returns a missing expression.

I need data from the same table but with a different parameter that cannot be combined in the same query.

TABLE TTT

```
DATE        LIC      ITEM   QTY  SU
20-01-2019  L991234  P0042   20  S002201
20-01-2019  L991234  P0042   40  S002202
20-01-2019  L991234  P0042   60  S002203
20-01-2019  L991234  P0042   80  S002204
20-01-2019  L991234  P0042  100  S002205
21-01-2019  L991245  P0069   30  S003101
21-01-2019  L991245  P0069   60  S003102
21-01-2019  L991245  P0069   90  S003103
21-01-2019  L991245  P0069  120  S003104
22-01-2019  L991256  P0042   20  S004301
22-01-2019  L991256  P0042   40  S004302
22-01-2019  L991256  P0042   60  S004303
22-01-2019  L991256  P0042   80  S004304
23-01-2019  L991264  P0069   30  S007501
23-01-2019  L991264  P0069   60  S007502
23-01-2019  L991271  P0042   20  S008801
23-01-2019  L991271  P0042   40  S008802
```

Query:

```
SELECT TA.ITEM, TA.CNT, TB.CNT
FROM (
SELECT  1 typ, DISTINCT TTT.ITEM, TTT.NO, COUNT(DISTINCT TTT.LIC)
    FROM TTT
    WHERE TTT.TYPE = '6' AND TTT.ITEM = 'H01234'
    GROUP BY   TTT.ITEM,TTT.LIC
    ORDER BY TTT.ITEM, TTT.NO
) TA
INNER JOIN
  (
SELECT  2 typ, DISTINCT TTT.ITEM, COUNT(DISTINCT TTT.SU)
   FROM TTT
        WHERE TTT.TYPE = '6' AND TTT.ITEM = = 'H01234'
        GROUP BY   TTT.ITEM, TTT.SU
        ORDER BY TTT.ITEM
) TB ON TA.ITEM = TB.ITEM
ORDER BY TA.ITEM
```

EXPECTED RESULT

```
TA.ITEM  TA.CNT  TB.CNT
P0042         3      11
P0069         2       6
```

Comment: i don't see the column  TA.FROM_ITEM  and  TB.FROM_ITEM in your subquery  ..  so you can't join  ..

Comment: My bad, should be TA.item = TB.item (I had changed the names of the fields to simplify and i missed these 2)

Comment: Your query is invalid. Both in Oracle and SQL Server - or any other DBMS for that matter. **1)** `SELECT  1 typ, DISTINCT` the keyword `DISTINCT` belongs right after `SELECT`. **2)** Where does `TTT.NO` come from? It isn't in your table. The select list and the group by in TA don't match. And what are you trying to do anyway? In TB you group by `TTT.SU` and then you `COUNT(DISTINCT TTT.SU)` which is always 1 of course. And your `DISTINCT` on an aggregated data set looks dubious to say the least.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it much simpler, without joins and unions:

**<sup>[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=91bceafc7884432fdf99775a03a8cced)</sup>**

```
select item, count(distinct lic) cnt1, count(distinct su) cnt2
  from ttt 
  group by item
```

Result:

```
ITEM        CNT1       CNT2
----- ---------- ----------
P0042          3         11
P0069          2          6
```

Answer (score 0):

`DISTINCT` should follow `SELECT`; you've got two consecutive `=`s

After that being fixed, query looks OK (but I don't know whether it returns desired data):

```
  SELECT TA.ITEM, TA.CNT, TB.CNT
    FROM (  SELECT DISTINCT 1 typ,                        --> here
                            TTT.ITEM,
                            TTT.NO,
                            COUNT (DISTINCT TTT.LIC)
              FROM TTT
             WHERE     TTT.TYPE = '6'
                   AND TTT.ITEM = 'H01234'
          GROUP BY TTT.ITEM, TTT.LIC
          ORDER BY TTT.ITEM, TTT.NO) TA
         INNER JOIN (  SELECT DISTINCT 2 typ,            --> here
                              TTT.ITEM, COUNT (DISTINCT TTT.SU)
                         FROM TTT
                        WHERE     TTT.TYPE = '6'
                              AND TTT.ITEM = 'H01234'    --> here
                     GROUP BY TTT.ITEM, TTT.SU
                     ORDER BY TTT.ITEM) TB
            ON TA.FROM_ITEM = TB.FROM_ITEM
ORDER BY TA.ITEM
```

Answer (score 0):

could be  that the join clause  is `ON TA.ITEM = TB.ITEM` and not ON TA.FROM_ITEM = TB.FROM_ITEM

```
    SELECT TA.ITEM, TA.CNT, TB.CNT
    FROM (
        SELECT  1 typ, DISTINCT TTT.ITEM, TTT.NO, COUNT(DISTINCT TTT.LIC)
            FROM TTT 
            WHERE TTT.TYPE = '6' AND TTT.ITEM = 'H01234' 
            GROUP BY   TTT.ITEM,TTT.LIC
            ORDER BY TTT.ITEM, TTT.NO
    ) TA
    INNER JOIN  ( 
        SELECT  2 typ, DISTINCT TTT.ITEM, COUNT(DISTINCT TTT.SU)
           FROM TTT 
                WHERE TTT.TYPE = '6' AND TTT.ITEM = = 'H01234'   
                GROUP BY   TTT.ITEM, TTT.SU
                ORDER BY TTT.ITEM
    ) TB ON TA.ITEM = TB.ITEM
    ORDER BY TA.ITEM
```